# jQuery Select2 -Zoom in on IOS / Tablets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are using the select2 plugin (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for dropdowns in our website - basically we are having an issue where it tries to zoom in on the selected text element within the drop down if clicked - this happens on IOS mobile devices.

I have tried to counteract this by using the following meta tag -

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Although the page now doesn't scroll - it still zooms when clicked.  has anyone had any similar issues